# How can I properly aim frontal cone attacks?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Frontal AoE attacks (generally known as "cone" to ranged and "cleave" to melee) such as [Cone of Cold](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=120) and [Dragon's Breath](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=31661) are extremely useful in PvP... When they don't miss. However, when they do miss, not only have I wasted a GCD, but I have also opened myself up to attack since I have to be in melee range to make use of them.

When I see other players in PvP (eg. on YouTube), they rarely seem to miss even though the effect of their AoE's don't always visually contact their target.

How can I ensure that I don't miss front AoE attacks?

Comment: The #1 thing you can do to improve accuracy with conal attacks: Not Keyboard Turn.

Comment: Also, know your latency so you can time around it.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I honestly can't even imagine playing the game and turning with the keyboard...

Comment: @Koviko Which is why I didn't post that as an answer - for most folks, it's just a given. But it is true that it's the number one thing that makes the biggest difference. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the best way to aim frontal cone attacks is the make sure YOUR CHARACTER (and not just the camera) is generally facing the target of the cone attacks. Keyboard turning can be very inaccurate some times and 9 times out of 10 someone will tell you to use the mouse to turn (holding r-click). In my opinion, the most effective way to do this, is by using the mouse's r-click to line your character's front with the target and with lag timing (counting your ms) aiming ahead relative to the speed of the target within that lag-time-frame.